# Conferir campos de senha um com o outro em java no spring

Tags: java

Como faço para validar dois campos de senha se ambos estão iguais

```
Usuario usuario = (Usuario) target;
        if(usuario.getSenha().equals(usuario.getSenha2())) {
                    errors.rejectValue("senha2", "field.compare");
                }
```

Comment: Gerson, edite o seu post e coloque o código formatado. Fora isso, o seu código já está comparando as duas senhas, logo, não entendi bem qual é a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Faça mais ou menos assim man.

```
campo1.getText();
    campo2.getText();

    if(campo1.equals("campo2")){
    //Executa função para senha igual
    }else{
    //Executa função para senhas diferentes
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if((campo1.getPassword()+"").equals(campo2.getPassword()+"")){
    //verdadeiro
}else{
    //falso
}
```

Tente não usar o `getText()` em campos *JPasswordField*, pois ele foi descontinuado para esse elemento.